# Is It possible to access to sharepoint graph api without provide azure app registration delegate and application permission in Angular

Tags: angular, azure, single-sign-on

we created angular application and then enabled single sign on with help of azure app registration, MSAL library.

Our Requirement is to access share point document graph api without make delegate and application level permission in app registration instead in angular app interceptor map to set specific scope permission.

**Code:**

export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array>();
protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/test', ['user.read']);
protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/test', ['AllSites.Read']);

return {
interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
protectedResourceMap
};
}

After set and access SharePoint graph api from angular, we got 403 issue. access denied. Please help if something missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need user or admin approval for accessing protected resources. Depending on the policies in your company users might be able to approve the app's access to sharepoint, however it can also be that this is prohibited and you need admin approval and that's done in the App Registry.